# Is there a way to export Advanced Custom Fields data?

Tags: advanced-custom-fields, export

I've entered data into ACF using the ACF Options plugin. Is there a way to export all that data I entered? When I use ACF's built in exporter, it only exports the structure. Maybe I'm missing something obvious.

Comment: Yes, however I'm wanting to export data entered using the ACF Options plugin. As far as I can tell from Googling, nothing like that exists.

Comment: What is the `ACF Options plugin`?

Comment: @jgraup I think he means the [ACF options page add-on](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/add-ons/options-page/).

Comment: @milo I'm guessing he's moved on since 2013... didn't see the date till I added the comment

Comment: You can check all data from wp_postmeta in database.

Comment: On 2022 there are some payment options: https://www.wpallimport.com/export-advanced-custom-fields/ https://www.smackcoders.com/wp-ultimate-csv-importer-pro.html